# Security Azure resources from attacks

Tags: azure, azure-security

I have certain azure resources like AKS, redis, cosmos, APIM etc. To secure the resources from attacks like DDOS, we put them all in private vnet and made them accessible only via APIM. Is that the right approach? In this case we only need to worry about the security of APIM. However the cost associated with vnets are high and we are evaluating other options. One thing I see is DDOS protection plan which protects the whole RG. So another approach is to remove the VNET and make the RG protected with the DDOS protection plan. However, are there any other attacks which are possible even with DDOS protection plan? Whats the best way to address them? Any leads will be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

you could use service endpoints for cosmos and restrict access only from vnet. For aks you can use loadbalanceripranges construct of k8s to whitelist ip's from api gateway.